# How to control .xib views

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiview, interface-builder, xib

I have a .xib file that I created by itself. I was wondering what the best way is to display that .xib when I click on a button. The .xib isn't full screen, it is only 200 x 200. I want to be able to control the .xib also, because it has buttons on it. Should I create a new class, if so, how do I connect the .xib to the class.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new class with an IBOutlet property `mySquareView`. In the IB set owner type to this class and connect your view to the property. Then work just if it was xib of a normal view with a view controller.

In order to load your view from xib, use an instance of your owner class and use the `instantiateWithOwner:options:` method of the [UINib](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINib_Ref/Reference/Reference.html) class.

You can also check the *Loading Nib Files Programmatically* section of this part of [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/CocoaNibs/CocoaNibs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000051i-CH4-SW8) provided by Apple.